# libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

Tags: lxml

I am installing [dragnet](https://github.com/seomoz/dragnet#evaluating-content-extraction-models) in python.
I got this error at the time of installation.

```
dragnet/blocks.cpp:261:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
```

After google for the issue I got to know that this will solve my problem

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

When I do so I get this

```
libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.2+zdfsg1-4) but 2.9.2+zdfsg1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
```

I am using **ubuntu-15.04**.